# AJAX post value is received as empty in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post values to another page and do some mysql operations but the values are posting as empty objects. This is my scripting part of the index.php file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#picker").datepick();
    $('#picker').datepick('setDate', 'today');

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "new_prob_submit.php", 
            data: { 
                'date': $('#picker').val(), 
                'name': $('#name').val() 
            },
            success: function()    {
                alert("success");
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

This is the PHP page where my posted values should be handled, new_prob_submit.php:

```
$rep_date = $_POST['date'];
$date = date("yyyy-mm-dd",strtotime($rep_date));
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infra.prob_report WHERE prob_rept_name = '$name'");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $nestedData=array(); 
    $nestedData[] = $row["rep_id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["prob_rept_date"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["prob_equip_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["prob_rept_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["prob_desc"];
    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You have to use `success: function(data) `.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi true, although his issue is that values are not received on the server, not as a result of the request. OP, your code looks fine. How have you determined that the values are not read in PHP?

Comment: Did you try to alert the values of your data? Are they filled correctly?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes you are right.

Comment: try to use `dateType:"json"` in your `ajax`.

Comment: What type of elements are `#picker` and `#name` `inputs` or ?

Comment: mysql result set returns rows which are empty values of column 'prob_rept_name '

Comment: @SatoshiKouno  ya I alerted in the click event data are filled correctly in respective fields but the issue is while posting

Comment: @BalajiRavichandran so if you analyse the request in the browser developer tool I expect you have those values or are they already empty in the request?

Comment: @Armen #picker is date field for listing out issues raised date and #name field is for the person who raised issue

Comment: if it will work, it returns you multi dimensoinal array like [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

Comment: first of all confirm that the values are available before the ajax call.so try to alert  $('#picker').val() and $('#name').val() .

Comment: @BalajiRavichandran Please check my answer.

Comment: he is already checked your answer that same as other mate... :p @ParthTrivedi

Comment: @devpro yes i have commented that first and have better explain what is going wrong in his code.

Comment: yes @ParthTrivedi: checked, good work.

Comment: @BalajiRavichandran: what is the reason of this?  $nestedData[] = $row["prob_desc"];
    $data[] = $nestedData;   multi dimensional... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you have not used

`dataType:"json"` in your `ajax`.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "new_prob_submit.php", 
            //added type
            dataType:"json",
            data: { 
                'date': $('#picker').val(), 
                'name': $('#name').val() 
            },
            success: function()    {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
```

Please check [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: ya noted well and in future won't commit this issue..thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

```
 $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "new_prob_submit.php", 
                data: { 
                    'date': $('#picker').val(), 
                    'name': $('#name').val() 
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                     alert(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please write explanation.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi  ya its working fine now thanks a lot for your valuable help!!

Comment: I posted example of code which working fine with me.just try to replace your $.ajax code and check it.I added dataType parameter which was not in your code

Comment: are u looking for multi dimensional array in ajax response? @BalajiRavichandran

Answer (score 1):

You are using `type: 'POST'` which is not correct, it must be `method: 'POST'` in your `$.ajax` object. make sure `console.log($('#picker').val(), $('#name').val() )` getting values in console.

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you script processData: true, like

```
  $.ajax({url: "submit.php",
       data: values,
       method: 'POST',
       processData: true,
       success: function (data) {
       alert(data);}});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.